# List header clicking in navigation drawer trigger home button(R.id.home) and closed the navigation drawer

Tags: android

Am using navigation drawer in my application, it opens perfectly over the toolbar when we click on the home button(R.id.home).

But when I click on the top left of the navigation drawer it trigger the home button again and closes the navigation drawer

Comment: Would help if you also post the code for your Navigation Drawer and all other things you think is necessary. The more info you provide, the better chances the community can provide a better answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for reply Peter O, the answer from Reza Bigdeli works fine,hope next time will do post with code for better understanding, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your navigation drawer probably is not clickable.
I suggest you try adding `android:clickable="true"` to your navigation drawer layout tag in your XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
.... >
<LinearLayout
...>
<!-- your main view -->
</LinearLayout>
<!-- drawer layout view -->
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="300dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true">
<!-- content of drawer layout -->
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```